# Netezza insert fail for DATE type value

Tags: date, insert, netezza

**Issue description:**

```
query = insert into tbl_test ("id", "date_col") values (?, ?)
cursor.executemany(query, [(1,'1955-05-20'), (1,'1955-05-20'),])
```

**Erro message:**

> internal error: Error executing query Operation canceled for query "
>   INSERT INTO "TBL_TEST" ("id", "date_col") VALUES (?, ?)"'

**nzlog:**
Load started at:06-May-14 22:24:39 EDT

```
  Database:         demo
  Tablename:        TBL_TEST
  Datafile:         /dev/null
  Host:             netezza
```

Load Options

```
Field delimiter:       '\t'               NULL value:            NULL
  File Buffer Size (MB): 8                  Load Replay Region (MB): 0
  Encoding:              INTERNAL           Max errors:            1
  Skip records:          0                  Max rows:              0
  FillRecord:            No                 Truncate String:       No
  Escape Char:           '\'                Accept Control Chars:  Yes
  Allow CR in string:    Yes                Ignore Zero:           No
  Quoted data:           NO                 Require Quotes:        No

  BoolStyle:             1_0                Decimal Delimiter:     '.'

  Disable NFC:           No
  Date Style:            YMD                Date Delim:            '-'
  Time Style:            24HOUR             Time Delim:            ':'
  Time extra zeros:      Yes
```

Found bad records

### **bad #: input row #(byte offset to last char examined) [field #, declaration] diagnostic, "text consumed"[last char examined]**

```
1: 1(2) [2, DATE] contents of field, ""[{]
```

Statistics

```
  number of records read:      1
  number of bad records:       1
  -------------------------------------------------
  number of records loaded:    0
```

=============================================================================

**nzbad:**

```
 1   {d '1955-05-20'}
```

**Table "TBL_TEST"**

```
 Attribute |  Type   | Modifier |   Default Value
-----------+---------+----------+--------------------
 id        | INTEGER | NOT NULL | -1
 date_col  | DATE    |          | '2013-01-01'::DATE
Distributed on hash: "id"
```

Reproduce the issue via nzload command per @Varun Bajaj suggestion:

```
nzload -u <userName> -pw <password> -db <database> -t <tableName> -delim , -df test.csv -host <hostIP> -bf testbf.log -lf testlf.log
```

**test.csv**

```
'1','1955-05-20'
'2','1955-05-21'
```

**testlf.log**

```
Load started at:07-May-14 05:13:35 EDT

  Database:         demo
  Tablename:        TBL_TEST
  Datafile:         /home/nz/test.csv
  Host:             netezza

Load Options

  Field delimiter:       ','                NULL value:            NULL
  File Buffer Size (MB): 8                  Load Replay Region (MB): 0
  Encoding:              INTERNAL           Max errors:            1
  Skip records:          0                  Max rows:              0
  FillRecord:            No                 Truncate String:       No
  Escape Char:           None               Accept Control Chars:  No
  Allow CR in string:    No                 Ignore Zero:           No
  Quoted data:           NO                 Require Quotes:        No

  BoolStyle:             1_0                Decimal Delimiter:     '.'

  Disable NFC:           No
  Date Style:            YMD                Date Delim:            '-'
  Time Style:            24HOUR             Time Delim:            ':'
  Time extra zeros:      No

Found bad records

bad #: input row #(byte offset to last char examined) [field #, declaration] diagnostic, "text consumed"[last char examined]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1: 1(2) [2, DATE] contents of field, ""[']

Statistics

  number of records read:      1
  number of bad records:       1
  -------------------------------------------------
  number of records loaded:    0

  Parsing Time (sec): 1.0
  Elapsed Time (sec): 1.0

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Load completed at: 07-May-14 05:13:36 EDT
=============================================================================
```

**testbf.log**

```
'1','1955-05-20'
```

Comment: I guess your program is appending "{d '1955-05-20'}" extra characters with your input also can you please paste following command output - "\d tbl_test".

Comment: Just for a sack of testing create a sample file with name sample.csv and paste those 2 lines in that file and run following command - 

nzload -u <userName> -pw <password> -db <database> -t <tableName> -delim , -df sample.csv -host <hostIP> -bf testbf.log -lf testlf.log 
"-quotedValue single"

I have marked "-quotedValue single" because the string you pasted above has no quotes on id but date, so either remove from both or put on both and try with this way, if error comes than please share testlf.log and testbf.log.

Thanks

Comment: "I have marked "-quotedValue single" because the string you pasted above has no quotes on id but date, so either remove from both or put on both"

As you have put quotes on values so use quotedValue argument with your nzload command.

Comment: Thanks @VarunBajaj, your suggestion works by adding "-quotedValue single" in nzload or remove single quote in test.csv; can I consult with you here whether there is ODBC api to set the attribute for 'quotedValue'? thanks a million!

Comment: Before exact answer to question i guess you are using Java as middleware and if your server is running on Linux than faster way is to write NZLOAD in bash and call shall script with Java else you can directly use nzload with help of external table option.